# MYSQL Group by and Group Concat issue

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I use `Group by` and `Group_concat` to achieve both cases below with 1 SQL query?

For case 1, even though the group id for device 1,2 and 3,4 is different, the output device id should still concatenate because the name and platform of group 1 and group 2 are the same.

```
CASE 1

Table: SMARTPHONE
==========================================
GROUP_ID    DEVICE_ID     NAME     PLATFORM
1           1             LG       ANDROID
1           2             APPLE    IOS
2           3             LG       ANDROID
2           4             APPLE    IOS    


Desired Output
ROW   DEVICE_ID
0     1,2,3,4
```

For case 2, because one of the name value in group 2 is different from group 1 
(i.e. Device 3, Samsugn is not equal to Device 1, LG) therefore it will be separated into two different groups.

```
CASE 2

Table: SMARTPHONE
==========================================
GROUP_ID    DEVICE_ID     NAME     PLATFORM
1           1             LG       ANDROID
1           2             APPLE    IOS
2           3             SAMSUGN  ANDROID
2           4             APPLE    IOS    

Desired Output
ROW   DEVICE_ID
0     1,2
1     3,4
```

It is like comparing all the values as a group. If the group has identical values to the other group, their id should be grouped together like case 1. If not, they should be separated.

What I have tried suggested by @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin.
For case 1, I tried `select 1 as grp,group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',')
from school group by grp
union
select GROUP_ID,group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',')
from school group by GROUP_ID` But I get

```
Output
ROW   DEVICE_ID
0     1,2,3,4
1     1,2
2     3,4
```

I am expecting if I run the query on case 1, it will give me the desired result shown in case one. If I run the same query on case 2, it will give me the desired result shown in case two.

Comment: Does `select 0, group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',') from SMARTPHONE` work? (Just guessing...)

Comment: @jarlh yes for case 1 only

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Im using mysql 5.6.38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select @rn := 0;
select @rn := @rn + 1 rn,
       group_concat(device_ids),
       names, platforms
from (
    select group_id,
           group_concat(device_id) device_ids, 
           group_concat(name order by name) names, 
           group_concat(platform order by platform) platforms
    from tbl
    group by group_id
) a group by names, platforms
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wtDVGzayWNP33XkpxXCMwY/0)

It uses double aggregation, first by `group_id`, then it groups by concatenated names and platforms are the same (I used `order by` to make sure that it will match indepenedently of order).

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you! Saved my life

Answer (score 1):

use group_concat

for case-1

```
 select 1 as grp,group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',')
    from SMARTPHONE group by grp
```

for case 2

```
select GROUP_ID,group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',')
from SMARTPHONE group by GROUP_ID
```

as you said to do  union both query so below is union operation

```
 select 1 as grp,group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',')
    from SMARTPHONE group by grp
union
select GROUP_ID,group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',')
from SMARTPHONE group by GROUP_ID
```

Comment: Tried this before, it will give me the output of case 2 for case 1

Comment: @JHO i eidted answer check please for case 1

Comment: Is it possible to do it with 1 query using if-else?

Comment: How can I union both query? Select ... union Select ... ?

Comment: @JHO union two query  done by the way your asking problem is solved my 1st answer , so if it helps please accept answer

Comment: Oh haha, sorry for my poor English. I was wondering if I can use 1 single SQL statement which will output different results for different cases

Comment: @JHO you edited your question and said what you tried ??? strange really you tried that or from answer you got that ???

Comment: added your name :) don't worry, not trying to steal your answer. But still not the answer for what I want

Answer (score 0):

Case 1:

```
select 0, group_concat(DEVICE_ID SEPARATOR ',') from SMARTPHONE
```